# Viewing applications in WPF with errors

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that breaks the image when the screen size changes

Below is the screen

Where can the mistake be? What can cause this situation? I do not even know where to look because it is not a permanent error only once and once is gone

This is how I load items with a line and number per view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorsGridsHorizontal, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Function drawing 1 element:

```
public Grid DrawConnector1(Thickness margin, int nr, bool rotate, bool rightSide)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Margin = margin;

    grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    grid.Width = S10;
    grid.Height = 128;
    grid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

    Line line = new Line();
    line.X1 = S10HALF;
    line.X2 = S10HALF;
    line.Y1 = 0;
    line.Y2 = 128;
    line.StrokeDashArray = new System.Windows.Media.DoubleCollection() { 4, 2, 1, 2 };

    line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
    line.StrokeThickness = 4;

    grid.Children.Add(line);

    Grid inGrid = new Grid();
    inGrid.Width = S10;
    inGrid.Height = HF;
    inGrid.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

    grid.Children.Add(inGrid);

    Border br = new Border();
    br.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
    br.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10);
    br.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    br.Margin = new Thickness(-10, -10, -10, -10);
    br.Width = 20;
    br.Height = 20;
    br.VerticalAlignment = rightSide ? VerticalAlignment.Top : VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    br.RenderSize = new System.Windows.Size(br.ActualWidth + 1, br.ActualHeight + 1);

    if (SelectedConnector + 1 == nr) br.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
    else br.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;

    if (DisableGreenMark) br.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;

    TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
    txtBlock.FontSize = 16;
    txtBlock.Text = nr.ToString();
    txtBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    txtBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    txtBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    br.Child = txtBlock;

    grid.Children.Add(br);

    Binding b = new Binding("S60_20");
    b.Mode = BindingMode.Default;
    grid.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, b);

    return grid;
}
```

GIF:

[image]

**I'm also using** `SnapsToDevicePixels="true"`

Comment: How's it resize - have you just stuck it in a viewbox or what? One simple quick fix might just be to use a viewbox. I'm not clear from watching your gif. Does it stay broken if you pick the "wrong" size or does it eventually look OK and the problem is related to rendering? Why are you using a grid rather than canvas for that DrawConnector? Grids are heavier performance wise because they force content to measure arrange. Canvas doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, try doing this:

```
br.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
br.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

- Do not use margin with a negative value
- Stretch will provide you with an element extension

Side cut is probably caused by too narrow a strip for the element:

You have:

```
grid.Width = S10;

line.X1 = S10HALF;
line.X2 = S10HALF;
```

This indicates that you have the width set to probably `10`

and Here you have set to `20`

```
br.Width = 20;
br.Height = 20;
```

I also suggest changing here:

```
grid.Width = S10 * 2;

line.X1 = S10HALF * 2;
line.X2 = S10HALF * 2;
```